# How to fix "Manifests for TfRecord ingestion must have exactly one tileset with exactly one source" in google earth engine

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-earth-engine

When I tried to upload the .tfrecord and .json file via earthengine command line in google colaboratory, it shows the "Manifests for TfRecord ingestion must have exactly one tileset with exactly one source." I am not sure where the problem is.

The code meets the problem is as followed:

```
outputAssetID = 'users/users_folder/s2_l8' 
!earthengine upload image --asset_id={outputAssetID} {outputImageFile} {outputJsonFile}
```

And the outputImageFile and outputJsonFile are all in Google Cloud Storage, with the name as follows:

```
gs://colab-sample-bucket-6561a9c6-a7a4-11e9-b2b3-0242ac1cxxx2/predictions.TFRecord
gs://colab-sample-bucket-6561a9c6-a7a4-11e9-b2b3-0242ac1cxxx2/predictions.json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
!earthengine --no-use_cloud_api upload image --asset_id={outputAssetID} {outputImageFile} {outputJsonFile}
```

If you're using the Python APIs, simply passing `--no-use_cloud_api` before uploading images will fix it.